# Localizing raw resource

Tags: android

I'm developing for english as my default language and swedish as a custom localization. I have values-sv for strings and it works fine. How do I make localization work for sound files as well? I would like to have duplicate sound files:

```
res/raw/instruction_00.ogg
```

and

```
res/raw-sv/instruction_00.ogg
```

But this won't be accepted: Eclipse complains that the music file already exists!

Comment: why not rename the audio file with the language suffix?

Comment: would that require me to add a string suffix each time I want to access a localized sound?

Comment: You should have different strings files for each language. Put the filename (i.e. instruction_00_sv.ogg) as a string in the proper language file, and then call the file in your code based on the string id which should be the same in all language files.

Comment: Well that makes more sense I guess. Still, would be more convenient if I could just name a raw folder based on language.